# CSS nth-child conditioning using LESS?

Tags: javascript, css, less

Let's say I have a listing with a default and active states determined by class, example:

```
<li class="item">
    item1
</li>
<li class="item active">
    item2 active
</li>
<li class="item active">
    item3 active
</li>
<li class="item">
    item4
</li>
```

**I need to add some extra styles based on whether the active items are next to each other** in the listing - as in the above case, that is true for item2 and item3, which are both active, but would not be true if it were item2 and item4.

I know how to determine this using plain JavaScript, but not sure if it could be a part of the LESS-generated stylesheet (which I would prefer and hence this question).

Comment: Do you want to apply the extra styles to *both* item2 and item3?

Comment: To every item except the last after the condition that they're together is met, so to item2 only in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in to CSS to cover both of these: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators.  Anything that LESS may provide would be a js extension.

Comment: Your answer made me realize I'm posing a wrong question, as you mentioned it would just be a js extension.